# Can't write to Docker volume

Tags: docker

#### My set-up

- I have a Docker image based on `php:7.4-apache`.
- I have two Docker volumes for saving files that need to be persisted.
- On container start, I run [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) to install HTTPs certificates.

#### Issue

I discovered that **my application can't write to Docker volumes**.

#### Debugging

Using `ls -l` I found out that the mountpoints of my volumes are owned by user `1451`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4     1451 users     176128 Mar 12 13:25 volume_mountpoint
```

My web server is running under user `www-data`.

#### Attempted solution

I've tried setting the user under which my container runs to `www-data`. This caused the volume mountpoints to be owned by `www-data`, which fixed the permissions issue. The problem with this solution is that `Certbot` requires `root` permissions and fails to acquire HTTPs certificate without it.

#### Question

What is the proper way to fix this issue? I need `Certbot` to run under root, but let mountpoints to be owned by `www-data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that worked for me in the past: create a new image out of the existing one and let entrypoint script of that new image to modify permissions of your volume_mountpoint.

So in the case of your image (php:7.4-apache) you create entrypoint.sh file, something like

```
chown www-data:www-data -R /path/to/volume_mountpoint
apache2-foreground
```

And then your Dockerfile should be something like

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

This way it should correct the permissions when container starts. Note, that I haven't tested the above, might require some tweaks - but hopefully it shows the idea.

P.s. Maybe somebody has a better way of doing this - I would be very interested myself.